# Find Range of Domain and Co-Domain

Tags: functions, integral-domain

Good Afternoon,

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how to find the range of a domain and co-domain?

For example, if A represents my domain and B represents my co-domain:

$A = \{q,w,e\}$

$B = \{r,t,y\}$

How do I work out the range of these?

Comment: You need a function, and the range of the function is the subset of the codomain whose elements are the values of the function.